# Cant retrieve error from procedure in PL/SQL

Tags: exception, plsql, procedure

I'm starting to work with PL/SQL and learning how to write `procedures` and `exceptions` but I cant seem to grasp how to show an error.  The procedure is a simple one, its only supposed to do simple math as you can see below:

```
create or replace
procedure get_simple_math
  (n_num1 in number,
   n_num2 in number,
   n_answer out number,
   n_err_code out number,
   n_err_msg out varchar2)
as
begin
  n_answer := (n_num1 / n_num2);
  dbms_output.put_line('Answer is '||n_answer);

  n_err_code := 0;
exception
  when others
  then
    n_err_code := SQLCODE;
    n_err_msg := 'Error in get_simple_math '||SQLERRM;
    raise_application_error (-20002,n_err_msg);
end get_simple_math;
```

As you can see its nothing fancy, but I cant for the life of me get the `block` to run:

```
set serveroutput on
declare
  n_answer number := 0;
  n_err_code number;
  n_err_msg varchar2;
begin
  get_simple_math(10,5,n_answer);
end;
```

I'm assuming I need to declare the variables that are set to `out`, which is why they are there.  I also tried adding them to the `procedure` execute like:

```
get_simple_math(10,5,n_answer,n_err_code,n_err_msg);
```

But that didn't seem to do the trick, so I am just looking for some help in solving this problem.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please _always_ post the error so that people know what to aim for. In this case a bit of rubber ducking ought to have helped. The error is _"ORA-06550: line 4, column 13: PLS-00215: String length constraints must be in range (1 .. 32767) "_, which tells you the exact location of the problem in your calling code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Run this and you'll get your answer:

```
declare
  n_answer number := 0;
  n_err_code number;
  --> n_err_msg varchar2; -- Incorrect
  n_err_msg varchar2(300);     -- Correct
begin
  --> get_simple_math(10,5,n_answer); -- Incorrect call to proc...
  get_simple_math(10,5,n_answer, n_err_code, n_err_msg); -- add out parameters
end;
/
```

General suggestion for the procedure part: use substr - optional:

```
  n_err_msg := 'Error in get_simple_math '||substr(SQLERRM, 1, 250);
```

Comment: Okay thank you very much, that was a silly mistake not to declare how big the `n_err_msg` variable was.  Thank you for helping out.

Comment: @glh Yeah I meant to but got caught up with something at work.